# Difference between OpenCart and WordPress setup with wp e-commerce

Tags: wordpress, shopping-cart, opencart

I am creating a site that only showcases catalogs of products.  But I want to keep open the option of adding a shopping cart experience later.  My usecase would be to create a site and then let the user themselves add or remove content from the site.

Which of the above (OpenCart or WordPress with wp e-commerce plugin) is a better choice?

Will OpenCart also allow the creation of some standard pages like about us, contact us page (with forms), etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi after scouring through dozens of pages, the impression I get is that, the upgrades of wordpress, e-commerce plugin and the theme you choose often lag behind one another,  leading to headaches.  So I am choosing to go with opencart.

Answer (score 2):

I have coded in wp ecommerce for about 13 months now. I have one of my plugins in Gold Cart and it is soon to be in the core.

As far as I know, wp ecommerce is not capable of allowing user submitted products.  I don't know of any plugins that do this either. Although - if anyone would have them it would be visser.com.au

In short, You would need to code a custom solution.

If you were looking to just have the products as a catalog, I would use css to hide the add to cart button, and I would ensure that the cart is not in a widget in the side bar. This would make the site function like a catalog but not allow the average user to add anything to the cart.

Adding extra pages for wp ecommerce is trivial - simply add a page in tghe wordpress 'page' menu then put the page in a menu.

I don't know much about open cart but I hope this helps with wp ecommerce.